# Stuck wake lock

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

In my app I always acquire a wake lock with an automatic time out but I have a report from user that the app holds a wake lock for hours (screenshot from battery consumption screen) thus causing battery issues. How can this code create a stuck wake lock?

```
final PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
final PowerManager.WakeLock lock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
lock.acquire(7000L);
```

I acquire wake locks in multiple places in my app and every one of them is with automatic timeout of few seconds.

Comment: Couldn't it be something else but the `WakeLock`? What is your code doing, that needs a `WakeLock`? If it's the `WakeLock` causing issues, could it be that it keep acquiring new locks over and over somewhere?

Comment: After acquiring the `WakeLock` I start an `IntentService` which opens a connection with a Wear watch and sends a message via the message API `Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(...).await()`. I have a detailed report from the user and the lock was taken ~50 times during the day, which is around 6 minutes in total but the system was reporting 7 hours.